# Passing custom objects between two iOS Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

I need some help on something. I have two apps under my account.

I need to pass a custom object from App A to App B. How can I do this using app groups ?

I saw that using URL schemes is a old a way of doing it.

So what is the newest way of passing data two apps ?

Comment: `1. UIPasteboard`, `2.AirDrop`, `3. URL Scheme`, `4. App Extension`  https://lionhylra.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/inter-app-communication-in-ios/

Comment: If your app is in the same app group, you can share datas between apps ( iOS8 +) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425706/share-data-between-two-or-more-iphone-applications

Answer (score 1):

**IN YOUR APP A (SAVE OBJECT)**

1. Under capabilities, Click "+" to add an App Group 
   [image]
2. In your Object Class, you need to extend the class you want to share to **NSObject** and **NSCoding**

   ```
   class Person : NSObject, NSCoding {
       var nom: String
       var prenom: String

       required init(name: String, prenom: String) {
          self.nom = name
          self.prenom = prenom
       }

       required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
           self.nom = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String ?? ""
           self.prenom = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "prenom") as? String ?? ""
       }
       func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
           coder.encode(nom, forKey: "nom")
           coder.encode(prenom, forKey: "prenom")
       }
   }
   ```
3. Save Data from your App A

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       let person = Person(name: "Ugo", prenom: "Marinelli")
       saveData(person: person)
   }

   func saveData(person : Person){
       //Map Class to recognize it
       NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("Person", for: Person.self)

       //Encode the object
       let personEncoded = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: person)

       //Push the object to the App Group
       UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.tag.testAppGroup")!.set(personEncoded, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
   }
   ```

**IN YOUR APP B (GET OBJECT)**

1. Add the same app group as the App A (see 1.1)
2. In the View controller you want to get the App A object :

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       //Class Mapping
       NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Person.self, forClassName: "Person")

       //Get The encoded data from App Group
       let personEncoded  = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.tag.testAppGroup")!.object(forKey: "FirstLaunch") as! NSData

       //Decode to get our Person object
       let personDecoded = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: personEncoded as Data) as? Person

       print(personDecoded?.prenom)
   }
   ```

**Note that you need to implement your Person class in both file, the best practice would be to create your own framework with your model in it**